# Form of the wave function in the TDSE

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

I was reading the derivation of **Expectation value of energy for an eigen-state $\psi_n(\overrightarrow{r,}t)$**

There $<E>$ is expressed as: $$\int_V{\psi_n^*}(\overrightarrow{r})e^{iE_nt/ℏ}\hat{E}\psi_n(\overrightarrow{r})e^{-iE_nt/ℏ}dV.$$
I don't have much knowledge about wave functions so I am  not able to understand how they expressed $\psi_n(\overrightarrow{r,}t)$ as $$\psi_n(\overrightarrow{r})e^{-iE_nt/ℏ}.$$
Is it some property of time independent wave functions? How do I know when to use this property? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SE is given by
$$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\Psi(t)\rangle =H|\Psi(t)\rangle  $$
A formal solution to this equation can be written as
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle =e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\Psi(0)\rangle$$
It's just like the equation $\dot{y}=ay$ with initial condition $y(0)$.

Now the eigenstate of the Hamiltonian defines as
$$H|\phi_n\rangle =E_n|\phi_n\rangle $$
So that we can write
$$|\Psi(0)\rangle =\sum_n|\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n|\Psi(0)\rangle \equiv \sum_n \psi_n(x)|\phi_n\rangle $$
At any time $t$, We have
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle =e^{-iHt/\hbar}\sum_n\psi_n(x)|\phi_n\rangle =\sum_n\psi_n(x) e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\phi_n\rangle =\sum_n \psi_n(x) e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}|\phi_n\rangle $$

On the other hand,
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle =\sum_n |\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n|\Psi(t)\rangle =\sum_n |\phi_n\rangle \psi_n(x,t)$$
comparing the two we have
$$\psi_n(x,t)=e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\psi_n(x,0)$$
which describes the evolution of eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.